# JQuery Datepicker Multiple Date Formats

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-format

I'm using JQuery Datepicker to output the selected date value to two different divs. I'm not sure how to get the value of the datepicker and apply two different formats.

This is how far I got:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd' });

    $("#datepicker").change(function() {
        $(".date-large").html($("#datepicker").val());
        $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', $(".date-small").html($("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate')));      
    });


  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use getDate method of datepicker to get current date from date picker.

In your code you have datepicker assigned to same element with 3 different option of date format, i am not sure that would work well as only the last line executed would be used. In your case small line dateformat will be used for #datepicker.

here is example of getting date form single datepicker.

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'D, M dd' });

    $("#datepicker").change(function() {
        $(".date-large").html($("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate'));

        // new edit
        var date_in_different_format = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', $( ".date-large" ).datepicker('getDate'));
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm okay I see that. But how can I extract two different date formats from the same picker?

Comment: I have also modified my answer! with // new edit.. you can get date in different format using dateFormat function provided with datepicker. i.e.           $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('getDate'));

Comment: I incorporated your suggestions, but now "date-small" is not displaying any text when I choose a new date. 'getDate' doesn't work since I don't think this outputs HTML. Any other ideas? (edited script in my original post)